# LEFT and charindex:Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql

What could be possible wrong with below query? I am trying to create a new column (**author_ref**) from existing column while stripping the all characters from left (column **author_name**) before space . Newbie to Cassandra.

> Select author_name, LEFT(author_name, charindex(' ', author_name)) from [author_by_id] as
> author_ref;

author_short;
TIA,
H

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have defined a user defined function called `LEFT` and `CharIndex` then it will not work, since there are no built in function of that name.

You can create custom functions although in this scenario, I would put the logic into the application / service and not push it to the database.